# Fixed minimum width for each value in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am looking for a way to set the min width for the space that each value can take on the x-axis. For example, in bar chart, if the window is narrow but number of different x values are large, then i can scroll to see the bars. By default, the bars will be squeezed together in a ugly way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create 2 , with one inside the other:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    <div id = "graph"> <!-- draw the graph in this div --> </div>
</div>
```

On top, draw the graph on the inner div with the desired width.
After doing it like this, you would be able to scroll if everything doesn't fit on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am actually looking for setting the width for each bar so they will not squeeze together when the screen is small. Can you provide an example?